# Как получить содержимое тега вместе с потомками, используя XmlPullParser?

Tags: android, xmlparser, java, теги

```
<doc>
 <element>
     <item>
     text1
     </item>
     <item>
     text2
     </item>
 </element>
</doc>
```

Необходимо получить содержимое тега "element" вместе с потомками, используя XmlPullParser. Как это сделать?

Comment: Поздрвляем.  Ну и что?)))

Answer (score 1):

Если парсниг не ограничивается только **XmlPullParser'ом**, то можно это сделать с помощью **JSoup**.

Если Вам необходимо получить все дочерние элементы тега **element** и они все одинаковы (как в предоставленном примере), то делается так:

```
final String xmlDoc = "Ваш документ";
final Document doc = JSoup.parse(xmlDoc);
final Elements items = doc.select("element>item");
String text;
for (Element el: items)
{
     text = el.text();
     // Что то делаете с полученным текстом
}
```

По поводу **JSoup** почитать можно [здесь](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)